# Inccorect work namespaces and composer autoload

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

My project work is fine on Windows.
When i try to run project on Ubuntu, i have error "Class ... not found"
Im using silex, silex classes and other vendor classes is ok.It is find. But my classes not find.
I used composer autoload. I fix my problem by composer comand "**composer dumpautoload --optimize**" but it is not ok?!

Why is that?

P.S windows(OpenServer - php 5.6)
ubuntu ( LAMP - php 7.0)

project [here](https://github.com/Vitaxxxa/l-systems)

Comment: Make sure that the folder names to your autoloaded files have the correct casing. Windows file system don't care about the casing, *nix systems do... On Windows: `some/folder` == `Some/Folder`, while on *nix: `some/folder` != `Some/Folder`. The same goes for filenames

Comment: @MagnusEriksson and "composer dumpautoload --optimize" - It may affect it?

Comment: It depends if that was the issue. Check your casing and give it a shot. Are you using psr-0 or psr-4 style autoloading?

Comment: psr-0. Okay, I'll check the code

Comment: Remember that all namespaces, files, folders and classnames _must_ have the same casing, or it will not work.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was in sensitivity

Comment: Added an answer so you can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the auto loaded files and folders have the correct (the same) casing as the namespaces and class snames. Windows file system don't care about the casing, *nix systems do...

On Windows:

```
some/folder == Some/Folder
```

While on *nix:

```
some/folder != Some/Folder
```